# Importing values into Google Spreadsheets are incorrectly converted to dates

Tags: google-apps-script

When importing a string value from a CSV file or inputting it from through UI Services that has a format similar to a date format (example:  cost center number of 2010-10), it is automatically converted to a date format (2010-10 is converted to 10/1/2010).  How can you tell Google to keep the value in string format?

Comment: Can you please add a code example.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a single quote ' before a value will tell google to treat the text as-is, rather than convert it to a date or a number. For example, entering `'2010-10` will show up as `2010-10` (i.e. the quote is not displayed) and will not be converted to a date.

I'm not sure how importing from a CSV file works, but you could massage the data there to avoid this problem. The quote character obviously works for entering anything directly from the console.